# Changing the url while loading different language

Tags: php, function, url-rewriting

I have this test website where there are 3 language options.
i have data stored in a database for all three languages.
What i want is, a function that works when someone clicks on different language link and when the data is loaded then the URL should also change something like
www.example.com/aboutus.php?lang=arabic.

this is my test website link

http://goo.gl/otp7pU

Comment: So what's your question? Like a statement, but with a question mark at the end?

Comment: Have you tried something? show some code. From your question we dont know, what exactly you want.

Comment: hi jahanzeb, i couldnt try anything because i dont really know how to go about it. for a better understanding you can see this "http://uae.souq.com/" here when you click arabic language option then the page reloades with arabic text, and the URL also changes.

Comment: Hi Dave, my question is how can i reload the page by clicking a link and adding post data in the url. like for english page it will be www.example.com?lang=en and arabic will be www.example.com?lang-arabic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a database for 3 different Languages, the best option for you would be to create 3 folders in your root directory, say lang-a, lang-b,lang-c.

Then, all the database requests in lang-a folder, queries the tables that have information stored  in lang-a. and same is the case with lang-b and lang-c folder. Each fetches data from their respective tables.

But, all the resources i.e. js, css and others will be the same for all three folders.

This way your url will also be different for all 3 languages as, say when lang-b is accessed the url will be :

www.yoursite.com/lang-b/index.html

for lang-c,

www.yoursite.com/lang-c/index.html

you can see a reference here:

Comment: hi free runner, i thought about this option but all the images will load again if i use different folder. i just want to reload the text on the same page and add a session variable in the url which will denote the language like en,ar,ru

Comment: when storing js, css, images etc. one level higher, you can access it from all of your language-subdirectories. And Session-Variables have nothing to do with GET-Parameters which is what you want. You can then additionally save the language in `$_SESSION`, but that is another story.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean with post-data is actually GET-Parameters.

You can access the content of the GET-Parameters via the `$_GET`-Variable like so:

http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=arabic

```
$lang = $_GET['lang']; // $lang is now 'arabic'
```